# Update @url path with different path parameters

Tags: android, retrofit2

```
Android - retrofit 2.9.0
```

I have the following retrofit method. I am using the @Url to include the base url and the path to search for products. However, I need to pass a `code` as part of the path. As I need to include the fullpath how can I add the code into the full url path?

`"https://myBaseUrl/v2/products/{code}/search"`

```
@GET
fun searchProductV2(
    @Path("code") storeCode: String,
    @Url fullPath: String = "https://myBaseUrl/v2/products/{code}/search",
    @Query("searchCriteria[pageSize]") pageSize: String,
    @QueryMap apiSearchCriteria: Map<String, String>,
    @HeaderMap headerMap: Map<String, String> = emptyMap()
): Single<Products>
```

Comment: There are string replace functions for that.

Comment: Can you explain why you just dont use a string replace function? Its pretty unclear to me what else should be needed. Can you tell how the result url would look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying won't work because if you specify `@Url`, it expects a static URL, it won't take `@Path` into consideration.

**Solution 1**

Remove the `@Path` parameter and just send the formatted string in `@Url`.

your method declaration will look like this:

```
@GET
fun searchProductV2(
    @Url fullPath: String,
    @Query("searchCriteria[pageSize]") pageSize: String,
    @QueryMap apiSearchCriteria: Map<String, String>,
    @HeaderMap headerMap: Map<String, String> = emptyMap()
): Single<Products>
```

and your `fullPath` parameter can be initialized like this:

```
val fullPath = "https://myBaseUrl/v2/products/%s/search".format("storeCode")
```

**Solution 2**

A better approach would be to **not** use `String` as the `@Url` parameter.
(`@Url` can be `okhttp3.HttpUrl`, `String`, `java.net.URI`, or `android.net.Uri`)

Here's an example using `android.net.Uri`:

your method declaration will look like this:

```
@GET
fun searchProductV2(
    @Url fullPath: Uri,
    @Query("searchCriteria[pageSize]") pageSize: String,
    @QueryMap apiSearchCriteria: Map<String, String>,
    @HeaderMap headerMap: Map<String, String> = emptyMap()
): Single<Products>
```

and your `fullPath` parameter can be initialized like this:

```
val fullPath = Uri.parse("https://myBaseUrl/v2/products/%s/search".format("storeCode"))
```

To make this code more nicer, you can create a helper class:

```
class DynamicUrl(private val formatString: String, private vararg val args: Any?) {
    fun toUri(): Uri = Uri.parse(formatString.format(*args))
}
```

and now your `fullPath` parameter can be initialized like this:

```
val fullPath = DynamicUrl("https://myBaseUrl/v2/products/%s/search", "storeCode").toUri()
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the obvious and simple solution...

```
@Url fullPath: String = "https://myBaseUrl/v2/products/" +storeCode+ "/search",
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the URL template with the `@GET` annotation
... and then substitute with the `@Path` annotation:

```
@GET("{baseUrl}products/{storeCode}/search")
fun searchProductV2(
    @Path("baseUrl") baseUrl: String = "https://myBaseUrl/v2/",
    @Path("storeCode") storeCode: String = "default",
    ...
): Single<Products>
```

Passing a constant value is also possible there:

```
@GET(Constants.API_BASE_URL_V2 + "products/{storeCode}/search")
fun searchProductV2(
    @Path("storeCode") storeCode: String = "default",
    ...
): Single<Products>
```

Or just the version `v2`, assuming a `BASE_URL` of `https://myBaseUrl/`. No matter how these are being combined, it needs to be a `String`, a constant value or a `@Path`, nothing else is permitted:

```
@GET(Constants.API_VERSION_V2 + "/products/{storeCode}/search")
fun searchProductV2(
    @Path("storeCode") storeCode: String = "default",
    ...
): Single<Products>
```

Generally speaking, there is no other way. This is because no parameter can be used as a substitution for another one parameter. This code doesn't run, but is only the `interface` definition, from which the corresponding runtime classes are being generated from - that's why trying to add custom code is pointless.

Not sure what `Single<Products>` is, but the default (unmapped / raw) return type would be `Call<ResponseBody>` in Java. The model class/es used for ORM (with GSON or Moshi converter) can use `@SerializedName()` to map the field names.

Comment: if you treat base URL as path, then the base URL that you set during retrofit initialization will also be used, so you will have base URL appended twice.